# Generic method to print arrays in java

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to write a generic method *printAll* which prints an array of integer or character.
Here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char cArray[] = {'a','b','c','d'};
    int iArray[] = {1,2,3,4};
    printAll(iArray);    // Error at this line--refer below the code

}

public static <T> void printAll(T[] t){
   for(T x:t) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
```

}

**Error**: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <.any>

Comment: use [Arrays.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[]))

Comment: By the way, that `T` there is pretty useless. You can declare the method `public static void printAll(Object[] t)` and it would work the exact same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`printAll(T[] t)` will not accept primitive type arrays. You need to pass arrays of the respective wrapper types:

```
Character cArray[] = {'a','b','c','d'};
Integer iArray[] = {1,2,3,4};
```

But, you don't need to frame your own method. Just use the already existing - [`Arrays.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28char%5B%5D%29) method, which is overloaded for different types of primitive arrays, and `Object[]` array.

Answer (score 7):

Do not reinvent the wheel, use [`Arrays.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28char%5b%5d%29) or [`Arrays.deepToString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29). The former already is overloaded to support arrays of primitive (as noted in the first link that receives a `char[]`), the latter works only on arrays of class references objects.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use primitive types with generics. Use `Integer` (or the corresponding reference type)

```
Integer iArray[] = {1,2,3,4};
printAll(iArray);
```

You can always overload the `printAll` method for each of the primitive types.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe in doing peoples work for them, more to inform and teach how it can be done.

one easy and simple way to print arrays in java will be done through converting the array to a string then print. This works best as array lists. This can then be manipulated to print in a better format.

for example make an array list and add some values:

```
ArrayList<String> Array = new ArrayList<String>();
Array.add(1)
Array.add(2)
Array.add(3)
Array.add(4)
Array.add(5)
```

Then from here this can be printed by changing it to a string:

```
String str = Array.toString()
System.out.println(str);
```

this will print the following:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

you can then change the format of this by using replaceALL on the string before you print it:

```
String str = Array.toString().replaceAll("[\\[\\]]","")
```

This will now give:

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

That is pretty much it, from here you could add extra things like System.lineSeparator which you would use to replace thhe "," with a new line.

```
String str = Array.toString().replaceAll("[\\[\\]]","").replaceAll(",",System.lineSeparator());
```

This would make it print out like:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Generic {
    public static<T> void printArray(T[] list) {
        for(T in : list) {
            System.out.println(in);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] lit=new String[3];
        lit[0]="aiq";
        lit[1]="abusov";
        lit[2]="java";
        printArray(lit);
    }   
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61203956/edit) your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.